# Applications resolved by Intents with Extra "EXTRA_INITIAL_INTENTS" not shown

Tags: android, android-intent, kotlin, file-sharing

I am trying to share file with email clients and Google Drive. Now, in following code, only Google drive is opening and email clients are not opening at all.  I can provide equivalent Java code of following code if required

```
    val photoURI: Uri = FileProvider.getUriForFile(this, "com.emerson.oversight.com.emerson.oversight.provider",
            File(this.cacheDir.path + "/SensorReport.pdf"))

    val emailIntent = Intent(Intent.ACTION_SENDTO)
    emailIntent.data = Uri.parse("mailto:")

    emailIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, photoURI)
    emailIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_EMAIL, "asd@dsa.dsa")
    emailIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, "dsadsada")
    emailIntent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION)

    val driveIntent = Intent()
    driveIntent.`package`= "com.google.android.apps.docs"
    driveIntent.action = Intent.ACTION_VIEW

    val fileID = File(this.cacheDir.path + "/SensorReport.pdf")
    val url = "https://docs.google.com/file/d/" + fileID

    driveIntent.data = Uri.parse(url)

        val openInChooser = Intent.createChooser(driveIntent, getString(R.string.share_using))
        openInChooser.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_INITIAL_INTENTS, arrayListOf(emailIntent))
        startActivity(openInChooser)
```

**Please help**

Comment: Not familiar with kotlin but intentArray = new Intent[]{emailIntent}; and pass in intentArray like this  openInChooser.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_INITIAL_INTENTS, intentArray)

Answer (score 1):

You were almost there, the only missing piece in the puzzle is the `getPackageManager().queryIntentActivities` method that will return all activities that can handle your email intent. With the ResolveInfo returned you can build an intent for each email option to be displayed in the chooser. Then you can pass the array of those intents as `Intent.EXTRA_INITIAL_INTENTS`. You could even exclude certain packages if you like here. So the final part of your code would look something like this:

```
        val openInChooser = Intent.createChooser(driveIntent, getString(R.string.share_using))

        val emailOptionIntents = mutableListOf<Intent>()
        val resInfo = getPackageManager().queryIntentActivities(emailIntent, 0)
        if (!resInfo.isEmpty()) {
            for (resolveInfo in resInfo) {
                val emailOptionIntent = Intent(Intent.ACTION_SENDTO)
                emailOptionIntent.data = Uri.parse("mailto:")

                emailOptionIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, photoURI)
                emailOptionIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_EMAIL, "asd@dsa.dsa")
                emailOptionIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, "dsadsada")
                emailOptionIntent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION)


                emailOptionIntent.`package` = resolveInfo.activityInfo.packageName
                emailOptionIntents.add(emailOptionIntent)
            }
        }




        openInChooser.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_INITIAL_INTENTS, emailOptionIntents.toTypedArray())
        startActivity(openInChooser)
```

Comment: Did you have a chance to try this?

Comment: this is working for the android os<=9 but on Os=10 (Q beta on google pixel 2) not working properly what i mean is emailOptionIntents is having more item but on ui showning less item